# How many different expressions can you get by inserting parentheses into: $x_{1}-x_{2}-\cdots-x_{n}$?

Tags: combinatorics

I ran into this question and I am finding it very difficult to solve:

> How many different expressions can you get by inserting parentheses into:
>   $$x_{1}-x_{2}-\cdots-x_{n}\quad ?$$

For example:

$$\begin{align*}
x_{1}-(x_{2}-x_{3}) &= x_{1}-x_{2}+x_{3}\\
(x_{1}-x_{2})-x_{3}&=x_{1}-x_{2}-x_{3}\\
x_{1}-(x_{2}-x_{3})-x_{4})&=x_{1}-x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}\\
\end{align*}$$

I'm really desperate for a full answer. I've been working on this for 3 hours. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on what the $x_i$ are.

Comment: so i have to solve it with sigma!!

Comment: @GitGud: I think the $x_i$ are supposed to be indeterminates - the question asks how many *expressions* can be made, not how many numbers.

Comment: Well you can't change the sign of $x_1$ or of $x_2$ by inserting brackets. The only changes the brackets effect are changes of sign. Does that observation help any?

Comment: I'm sensing generator functions might be necessary?

Comment: I am not sure if the list of expressions includes this type of expression: $$x_1 - (x _ 2 - x_3) - x_4 + x_4$$

Comment: @NasuSama $x_1-(x_2-x_3)-x_4+x_5=x_1-(x_2-x_3)-(x_4-x_5)$ - if you meant $-x_4+x_4$ those terms can be eliminated as equal to zero.

Comment: A plausible first guess is that for $n\geq 2$ the answer is $2^{n-2}$; clearly the sign of $x_1$ and $x_2$ can't change, and it seems as though it should be straightforward (though I haven't tried) to iteratively produce all sign combinations on the other variables.  (Although $x_1-x_2+x_3+x_4$ is at least at first glance non-trivial)

Comment: Noone has counted expressions of the form $(x_1-x)_2$, which is $x_1-x$ to the base $2$.

Comment: Does wrapping a single x in a parenthesis count as a different expression or is this just in simplified forms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is $2^{n-2}$.  $x_1$ must always be positive and $x_2$ must always be negative.  Then you can pick the signs on all the rest any way you want, starting with $x_3$.  For a string of length $n$, start with a string of length $n-1$ that has the signs the way you want up to there.  If you want the sign before $x_n$ to be negative, leave it outside the parentheses.  If you want it positive, add it to the last set of parentheses if $x_{n-1}$ is inside one, or group it with $x_{n-1}$ if not.  Steven Stadnicki's example of $x_1-x_2+x_3+x_4=x_1-(x_2-x_3-x_4)$

Answer (score 8):

HINT: No matter how you parenthesize the expression, when you clear the parentheses, the first two terms will be $x_1-x_2$. Show by induction that the remaining $n-2$ signs can be any combination of plus and minus signs, meaning that for $n\ge 2$ you get $2^{n-2}$ distinct expressions.